# Proving equality of conditional expectation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given Probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, Suppose $\mathbb{E}[X^2] < \infty .$ Let $$ Z:=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}] $$
Show that $$\mathbb{E}[(X-Z)^2]=\min_{y \in m\mathcal{F}} \mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]. $$

I don't know how to approach this problem. Actually cannot understand the condition $ Z:=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}] $ because then it will be $Z=X$ I guess? Someone could please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yon  can watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pWR01L6Rnk

Comment: this should follow directly from the fact that conditional expectation is orthogonal projection in $L^2$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'll check on that right away, thank you